# Calling Asynctask creating delay

Tags: android, android-asynctask

In my application, upon clicking login in the login page, I have to call 3 APIs. I have 3 AsyncTask to do this requirement. What I am doing is calling 2nd task inside the 1st task onPostExcecute() and the 3rd task is called inside the 2nd task's onPostExecute().

TaskA looks like:

```
private class TaskA extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, ListA> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {

    }

    @Override
    protected ListA doInBackground(Void... params) {
        ListA listA;//its an arraylist          

        listA = //calling my API

        if(listA != null) {
            //writing listA as serialized into sdcard.
        }

        return listA;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ListA listA) {
        for(ListAValues value : listA) {
            new TaskB().execute(value);             
        }
    }
}
```

TaskB:

```
private class TaskB extends AsyncTask<ListA, Void, ListB> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {

    }

    @Override
    protected ListB doInBackground(ListA... params) {
        ListB listB;//its an arraylist          

        listB = //calling my API

        if(listB != null) {
            //writing listB as serialized into sdcard.
        }

        return listB;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ListB listB) {
        new TaskC().execute(listB);
    }
}
```

TaskC:

```
private class TaskC extends AsyncTask<ListB, Void, ListC> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {

    }

    @Override
    protected ListC doInBackground(ListB... params) {
        ListC listC;//its an arraylist          

        listC = //calling my API

        if(listC != null) {
            //writing listC as serialized into sdcard.
        }

        return listC;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ListC listC) {
        //moving to my landing page.
    }
}
```

The problem is in the landing page, screen is blinking with black and white color.( White color is the background color for my landing page activity). Is the way I am implementing is right? Or do I need code to be changed? Please help me out.

Comment: i think u need to implement `AsyncTask.Status` for checking previous started task is completed or not .check status of previous task before starting new .this maybe helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rajesh, your code couldn't help me out.

My app is API level 11. So I used

```
Task.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.SERIAL_EXECUTOR)
```

This helped me out and my code is working fine.

Answer (score 2):

You do not need to use 3 separate `AsyncTask`s. You can use a single `AsyncTask` as follows:

```
private class TaskA extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        ListA listA;//its an arraylist          

        listA = //calling my API

        if(listA != null) {
            //writing listA as serialized into sdcard.
        }

        for(ListAValues value : listA) {
            ListB listB;//its an arraylist          

            listB = //calling my API

            if(listB != null) {
                //writing listB as serialized into sdcard.
            }
            ListC listC;//its an arraylist          

            listC = //calling my API

            if(listC != null) {
                //writing listC as serialized into sdcard.
            }


        }
        return null;
    }

}
```